# Error while installing nginx via brew

Tags: nginx, homebrew

Brew install `nginx`, gives me this error. Forgive my ignorance, I am new to the Mac. >**Error:** cannot load such file -- requirements/osxfuse_dependency**

> **Please report this bug: http://git.io/brew-troubleshootin**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/requirements.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/dependency_collector.rb:4:in`'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:9:in`'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/missing.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1:in`'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'**
>   **/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:59:in`require?'**
>   **/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:118:in `'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of troubled hours, finally found out a solution.

**Solution:** First run `brew update` and then `brew install nginx`